# width of splitter using dojo containers

Tags: dojo, styles, splitter

I am using dojo containers with the splitter.  As far as I can tell, the splitter is either true or false.  My customers are having a hard time grabbing the splitter. I'd like to make it a little wider. But I don't see any way to control the width.

```
<div id="sidepanel"  data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'leading'"style=" width: 285px">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #1">accordion pane #1</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #2">accordion pane #2</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #3">accordion pane #3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width and any other style of the splitter can be controlled using css:

```
.dijitSplitter {
  width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Ah!  It's .claro .dijitSplitter{}  Thanks for the lead!

Comment: FYI to others:  height: 15px for horizontal splitters.